# How a code with the lamda expression on construction of a entity works

Tags: c#

What is the meaning of the below code,

```
var personDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        var grid = new Grid();
        ...
        var nameLabel = new Label { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold };
        var ageLabel = new Label();
        var locationLabel = new Label { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End };

        nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");
        ageLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Age");
        locationLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Location");

        grid.Children.Add(nameLabel);
        grid.Children.Add(ageLabel, 1, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(locationLabel, 2, 0);

        return new ViewCell { View = grid };
    });
```

How the code runs with the below instance,

```
new DataTemplate(() => { --- How the code runs here --- })
```

Is it like a self invoking function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTemplate's constructor has a parameter that takes a delegate, probably something like

```
public DataTemplate(Func<ViewCell> foo)
```

By calling `() => {}` you define anonymous method(lambda expression).

Inside `DataTemplate` it is called somewhere like this:

```
ViewCell bar = foo();
```

You can use it to allow users to define their own instance of `ViewCell` that should be used inside.

Comment: Thank you for replying. So if i need to send parameter to the anonymous method, do i send it like (param) => {} ?

Comment: @AryanM Yes. For example `Func<int, double> foo;` can be invoked as `myInt => {return (double)myInt; }`. If you don't want any return type you can use `Action` instead of `Func`.